# Cart is showing same products for all users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My cart is displaying same products for all users. I am using laravel built in auth and I have checked other answers where session is used. But I want to do it with auth.

**CartController.php**

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        if (Auth::check()) {

            $cart = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('product_id', $request->product_id)
                ->first();

            if ($cart) {
                $cart->increment('product_quantity');
                $cart->save();
            } else {
                Cart::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'product_id' => $request->product_id
                ]);
            }

            session()->flash('success', 'Product has added to cart !!');
            return back();
        }
    }


    public function show()
    {
        
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $cart= Cart::all();
            return view('frontend.pages.cart')->with('carts', $cart);
        } else {
            session()->flash('status', 'No cart items added');
        }
    }
```

Please help with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are retrieving all products  from cart so it should be

```
$cart= Cart::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

or add relationship in User model

```
public function cart(){
 
  return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
}
```

and in controller

```
$cart=auth()->user()->cart;
```

Comment: I have done all of this except the third one. But still same .

Comment: @TanjibRubyat defiantly $cart= Cart::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->all(); wont return all because it only return that user cart product

Comment: I have updated my question . Please check my code if I have made any mistake

Comment: Now I am getting a new error when I try to view cart items. The error is :   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: @TanjibRubyat sorry its my mistake it should be get() not all() .i

Comment: Alright, I think it worked. But the cart icon is showing number items same for both users.

Comment: @TanjibRubyat there also you have to get count unsing same where condition

Comment: Please can you tell me more in details ?

Comment: @TanjibRubyat $cartCount= Cart::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->count(); or you can do count((array)$cart)

Comment: Yes, I understood. Its resolved now. Thanks for your help. Everything's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first, make sure, that Auth::id() returs proper ID. You can also try Auth::user()->id.
2. Check if the relationship between cart and product is correctly formed
3. I am not sure what you want to list all carts for. Maybe it's a mistake in show function using Cart::all()?

Comment: Yes, Auth::user()->id returns proper id.